# How to keep an Amazon ElastiCahe Memcached/Redis before a RDS MySQL database and use ElastiCache to cache the content?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elasticache

What is the process of keeping ElastiCache infront of RDS MySQL database?

Answer (score 1):

Your application code needs to always check the cache first, and use the cached value if it is there. If not, then your application needs to query the database, get the value, insert it into the cache, and then proceed. There is no automated method of doing this from an infrastructure standpoint. It is up to your application to do this.

Depending on what application frameworks you are using there may be a way to configure your application to do this easily without having to code all the logic yourself.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I have two questions which are as below. 1) I created one cluster in ElastiCache and connected that cluster with EC2 instance. And I want to include ElastiCache infornt of my RDS(MySQL database). What is the process to do that? Also is there anything needs to be done from infrastructure side? 2) Is there any sample application(Java/Mean Stack applications) which will perform the actions what you mentioned such as checking Cache, querying the database, get the value, insert into the cache. Thank you.

Comment: @GayathriK I feel like my answer already answers your first followup question. It seems like you are just restating your original question, which is what I answered. There is nothing that needs to be done from the infrastructure side, since this isn't something that can be accomplished at the infrastructure level, it needs to be accomplished at the application level. For your second question, asking for sample applications is generally off-topic for this site. I don't have any specific samples to point to, but I'm sure you can find something if you search.